# PDF generation performance ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, performance, pdf, sharepoint-2010, pdf-generation

I'm building an ASP.NET site right now where we're replacing every print button with a download pdf button. This for the simple reason that we want the response to be uniform across all browsers with our own brand printed on it.

It works great and the generated pdfs are perfect (EO.PDF). However it seems to take quite a bit of load.

Now I'm wondering, are there good techniques I could use to improve performance? Throttling, 'send via email', etc.

I don't understand much about multithreading, but is there a way of splitting one thread into two virtual threads and assign a specific set of resources to one? Or maybe assign one specific thread only to be used for PDF generation and have it inactive in any other event?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While EO.PDF is "thread-safe", at least as of EO.PDF 2011/3.x, it serializes everything - that means, threading does not help EO.PDF performance at all. While running EO.PDF as background service will keep it from "hanging" a response, it also changes it into an asynchronous process - this may or might not be OK but is an entirely different approach.

If using the EO.PDF support to convert another ASP.NET page, performance increases might be obtained by ensuring that page is quickly loaded. EO.PDF does support caching, but I am not sure if this persists between different processes. In this aspect, consider analyzing the web-requests generated by EO.PDF to see if there are any serious bottlenecks that can be improved.

Also, make sure to grab the latest version your license allows ..